# Installation Issues on Asus X555UB

Tags: system-installation

I got a new laptop and wanted to install Ubuntu on it but I am having so many problems with the install. Usually what happens is I will start the installation and will get hung up with a `ubi-timezone failwed with exit code 1` message. Sometimes the installation gets past that. What I've noticed is when it is installing if I expand the message section I can see a constant flood of errors. I can't really read them quick enough but I took a picture and was able to capture most of the message which is:

```
PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer id=00e5
device[8086:9d15] error status/mask=00000001/00002000
```

I'm not sure what is going on here, but I'm extremely frustrated. Anyone have any ideas on how I should continue getting Ubuntu on my machine? I've tried to get Mint working also but the PCIe Bus Errors prevent me from even starting up.

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't much help but I just used a search engine for your specific error and came up with this: https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/9/2/573 I'm adding this as a comment because it may help someone else to better find an answer for you.

Comment: I have that laptop, and I have no issues running ubuntu 12.04.  you might check the intergrity of your liveUSB media. You might also try booting into the live session of ubuntu prior to tying to install.  pci port, is probably your wifi adapter.  Youll want to be connected to the internet,  for installation,  although its not required, Ethernet is better, if you can.

Comment: I verified the integretity of the liveUSB and it turned out that it was corrupted. I switched to using unetbootin to make the USB and verified the contents and it looks like that is good now. However I got althe way to installation, and it crashed and told me "The problem cannot be reported: This is not a genuine Ubuntu package". I was hoping I could peek at some logs, but since I did it without the live preview, when it tried to switch over the message spam above took over and I couldn't do anything. Any thoughts on what I should look into to fix this?

Comment: Could you run the live installer, and add the output of `lspci -v`, `lsusb` `lsusb -t` to the question plz? (by [edit]ing)

Comment: I had the very same problem (same numbers too); integrity check reported corrupted system, I reinstalled it from another drive and it worked.

Comment: UPDATE: I have removed and tried to reinstall another version, this time it doesn't fail the integrity check but still reports the errors. (First try that reported to be corrupted and gave PCIe bus errors: Linux Mint 17.3; Second try that worked: Linux Mint 17.2; Third try that passed integrity check but gave PCIe bus errors: Ubuntu 15.10; all versions were 64bit). NOTE: first and third try were hardware-accelerated, second try was software-rendered.

Comment: Have the same problem on my HP Probook 450 G3.
Please see what device connected to that pcie port using next command: `lspci -tv`.  In my case it is *Intel Corporation Wireless 3165*. Please see what device connected to that port and report about it.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this laptop and issue, but using Fedora 22. Supposedly, this is the laptop's firmware not implementing Active State Power Manager correctly. You can tell the Linux kernel not to use ASPM by adding this kernel parameter: `pcie_aspm=off`. I don't know if this is better or worse than KGill's suggestion of `pci=nomsi`.